# how to do dot multiplication of vector and sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, numpy-ndarray

how to do `dot` multiplication between vector and matrix (sparse)?

It works with vector (ndarray type) and normal matrix (ndarray type).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import sparse

x1 = np.arange(8).reshape((2, 4)) * 10
x2 = np.arange(4).reshape((2, 2))

x1
# array([[ 0, 10, 20, 30],
#        [40, 50, 60, 70]])
x2
# array([[0, 1],
#        [2, 3]])


# works
x2[1,].dot(x1)
# array([120, 170, 220, 270])
```

But doesn't work w/ sparse matrix (becomes elementwise)

```
x1 = sparse.csr_matrix(x1)
x2[1,].dot(x1)
# array([<2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
#   with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
#        <2x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
#   with 7 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)
```

How can I

Comment: `x2[1]*x1` might work.  Or `x2[1]@x1`.  Eitherway gives the sparse matrix control over the multiplication.  `x2.dot(...)` uses `x2.dot(np.array(x1))` which is wrong.  `x2.dot(x1.A)` should also work.

Comment: @hpaulj using `@` works! Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

`x2[1]*x1` might work or `x2[1]@x1`. Either way gives the sparse matrix control over the multiplication. `x2.dot(...)` uses `x2.dot(np.array(x1))` which is wrong. `x2.dot(x1.A)` should also work.
If you want short answer you can read this